# How to use Ctrl+R with setxkbmap option grp:lctrl_rctrl_switch?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout

I tried to use:

```
setxkbmap -layout us,ru -option grp:lctrl_rctrl_switch
```

Layout switching works as expected, but I cannot use key combinations like Ctrl+R, Ctrl+W, etc. How could it be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not very straight. The problem is that switching is done on pressing button, but should be done on releasing. This is an Xorg bug and somebody says Ubuntu don't have it.

So, if you do not want to change to Ubuntu you have to use other switching software (loloswitcher is proved to have no such bug).